# HOT MODULE replacement react-native

Tags: react-native

This is not a duplicate of this thread
[Live reload in react-native without resetting the route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684103/live-reload-in-react-native-without-resetting-the-route/34684334#34684334)

that thread is already 2 months old and there is no activity on that one.

I have seen many commits like this one https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/e018aa3100d93abf0e222cd70bbcbb6ab248eced regarding HMR

But have not seen any documentation on how to enable it.

Is it possible to do HMR now in react-native?

There is a library `react-transform-hmr` which works for older version of react-native.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out, react-native `0.22.0-rc` ships with `HOT RELOADING`.

Comment: @andy Is it against the rule to celebrate?